# Downloading/Opening .csv file using Google chrome, it changes extension of .csv file to .xls

Tags: html, csv, google-chrome, download, anchor

I have an `a` tag in my html file that is pointed to a `.csv` file. Every time I click on the link it downloads the same file in `.xls` extension. Why?

I tried the following:

```
<a href="./example.csv" target="_blank">File download</a>
<a href="./example.csv" download>File download</a>
<a href="./example.csv" type="text/comma-separated-values">File download</a>
<a href="./example.csv" type="text/csv">File download</a>
```

I tried to open the file with the `file:///myfolder/example.csv` protocol but all of these had the same outcome.

Whereas in Firefox, IE, Edge this downloads the file in `.csv` extension.

How can I get chrome to download the `.csv` file in the `.csv` extension?

Comment: Seems like a Chrome bug. I can reliably replicate this by copy pasting the path of any local .csv file into the address bar, and it downloads as a .xls

Comment: I am getting this issue also

Comment: I came across the same issue in normal window. But I can download the file with correct extension in seamless window. Not sure if any plugin affects its behavior.

Comment: I've tried to workaround this issue, without success. Opened a bug for chrome  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1074202

Comment: In my case the .csv was downloading as .txt, and in Edge wasn't working either so it might not be the same case but for me worked specifying the file name in the download property, in this case: <a href="./example.csv" download="example.csv">File download</a>

Answer (score 0):

Locally on Windows 10 machine Google Chrome downloaded .csv file with .xls extension. But when I uploaded the same project to GitHub Pages, Google Chrome started downloading file with correct .csv extension.

So the solution is either in webserver settings or just to test outside of the local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried supplying a value to the download attribute, like this?

```
<a href="./example.csv" download="example.csv">File download</a>
```

That may be enough to force the server to download the file as you expect.  Also, try removing the "./" from the `href` attrbute of your `a` tag.

If you'd like to know more about the download attribute, [check this link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).

Answer (score -2):

I didn't find any solution for it so I have made a work around:

```js
      if (fileType === 'text/csv') {
        FileSaver.saveAs(newBlob, `${data}.csv`);
      } else {
        FileSaver.saveAs(newBlob, `${data}`);
      }
```

This is working for me, if you find that browser makes the same issue for any other file and this file is not csv, try to implement it like this and it will also work.

Comment: What is `FileSaver`?